# VirutualHost not working with live domain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost

recently I have installed a new cloud server for host 6 site. my problem is my site is not working with my main domain but its working with test domain properly.

My virtual host

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerAdmin admin@tempdomain.com
         DocumentRoot /var/www/domains/weddp
         ServerName tempdomain.com
         ServerAlias www.tempdomain.com
         ErrorLog /var/www/domains/weddp/error
    </VirtualHost>
```

I tested my site with a temp domain and its working fine but when I tried with my live domain its not working.

I just change my domain name on ServerName and ServerAlias everything other is remain same like

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerAdmin admin@tempdomain.com
         DocumentRoot /var/www/domains/weddp
         ServerName livedomain.com
         ServerAlias www.livedomain.com
         ErrorLog /var/www/domains/weddp/error
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What unexpected results do you get. Are there any relevant messages in your log files? And is your DNS configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason for it now to work is that your computer doesn't know any `livedomain.com` domains so by editing your `/etc/hosts` it will be able to resolve the domain properly.

Edit your `/etc/hosts` file and add `livedomain.com` to the `127.0.0.1 localhost` line and retry.